# how to assign links to class elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to assign links to my navigation bar with javascript. I've given my navigation links a class name: "navigation". It seems that the loop assigns all of my link elements with "javascript" in the end.

```
var myArray = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation"); // array
var text = ["HTML", "DOM", "Javscript"];

var a = document.createElement("a");

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var linkText = document.createTextNode(text[i]); 
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.href = "#" + text[i];
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

Comment: Move `var a = document.createElement("a");` inside the loop

Comment: because `a` is global variable and javascript assign value by reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one element, and it gets removed. So move the assignment into the loop:

```js
var myArray = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation"); // array
var text = ["HTML", "DOM", "Javscript"];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  var linkText = document.createTextNode(text[i]); 
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.href = "#" + text[i];
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

```css
a {margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="navigation"></div>
<div class="navigation"></div>
<div class="navigation"></div>
```

I have added the HTML / CSS as dummy stuff to recreate the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating anchor tag only once.

```js
var myArray = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation"); // array
var text = ["HTML", "DOM", "Javscript"];


for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  var linkText = document.createTextNode(text[i]);
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.href = "#" + text[i];
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation"></div>
<div class="navigation"></div>
<div class="navigation"></div>
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");     // Changed here
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(text[i]); 
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    a.href = "#" + text[i];
    document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/0xt7qokz/)